# Issue with Test Case Grader

Tags: python, debugging

I am attempting to debug a section of code that involves income brackets and have run into a problem involving test cases. No Syntax Errors whatsoever have been detected and I based it off of the income table as shown below:

[image: Table of Tax Rates Amount Owed by Income Bracket]

Here is the question:

> Complete the function `income_tax_single` which takes as its input the
> variables `income` (and `round_income`) and returns as its output the
> `income_tax` (or tax owed) and `tax_bracket` based on the rules described
> in the table above. For the purpose of the code, the `tax_bracket` is
> the tax rate below while the `income_tax` is the tax owed based on the
> income. The `True` or `False` input variable `round_income` determines
> whether the income is rounded before the calculations are performed.
> You can test your function in the scratchpad by supplying it with
> various values of the input for income and checking if the results
> match what you would get when you calculate it yourself. As a simple
> test case, setting `income = 4000` should return `tax_bracket = 0.1` and
> `income_tax = 400`, as we have previously shown.

Here is the error message: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c2yf.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
def income_tax_single(income, round_income = True):
    
    if round_income:
        income = round(income) # round to nearest integer
    else:
        income = income # do not round it
    if (income <= 9875) and (income > 0):
        tax_bracket = 0.1
        income_tax = (0.1 * income)
    elif (income >= 9876) and (income <= 40125):
        tax_bracket = 0.12
        income_tax = (987.50 + (0.12 * (income - 9875)))
    elif (income >= 40126) and (income <= 85525):
        tax_bracket = 0.22
        income_tax = (4617.50 + (0.22 * (income - 40125)))
    elif (income >= 85526) and (income <= 163300):
        tax_bracket = 0.24
        income_tax = (14605.50 + (0.24 * (income - 85525)))
    elif (income >= 163301) and (income <= 207350):
        tax_bracket = 0.32
        income_tax = (33271.50 + (0.32 * (income - 163300)))
    elif (income >= 207351) and (income <= 518400):
        tax_bracket = 0.35
        income_tax = (47367.50 + (0.35 * (income - 207350)))
    elif (income >= 518401):
        tax_bracket = 0.37
        income_tax = (156235 + (0.37 * (income - 518400)))                             
                      
    return tax_bracket, income_tax
```

I tried rerunning the code and asking GPT to no avail. I shut down and restarted the computer as well.

Comment: Can you post the original question? Your code looks fine, perhaps the question is asking for the answers in a different format.